# How do I get Webdriverio to work with appium-desktop inspector?

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-desktop

Webdriverio allows you to run appium as a background process. Docs [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/appium-service.html)

I'm looking to use the appium inspector to quickly get testID and native id information for selectors.

Is there a way to run the appium inspector alongside the webdriverio tests runner to inspect the app views?

Comment: Yes, sure. Just connect to existing appium instance instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 2):

in the webdriverio config just add:

```
path: '/wd/hub',
port: '4723'
```

Assuming appium server is running in 4723, Make sure to remove Service

Thats it :)